# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User' with Passport and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

Using PassportJS in Express with Typescript, I get the following error when trying to access `req.user.id`.

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
```

When logging just `req.user` to the console, I can clearly see that there is an id property, however Typescript is throwing this error none the less.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to run,

```js
userRouter.post("/session", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { startTime, endTime, desc } = req.body;
  const { user } = req;

  console.log(user!.id);

  res.json({ message: "CREATE NEW SESSION" });
});
```

As I am new with TS, I am unsure of the steps to take in resolving this problem. My guess is I have to change an interface or something in the configuration somewhere.

Comment: Does TypeScript know that this user object has an id property? What is the type definition of the User type? That's where you need to start.

Comment: Would that come from the `@types/passport` package, because I have that as a dev dependency? Otherwise I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: "logging just req.user to the console, I can clearly see that there is an id property" this doesn't matter at all. You are confusing *compile time* with *run time*. The compiler has to know, *at compile time*, that the property is included in the type definition. Any object other than an object literal can have extra properties the type-checker doesn't know about.

Comment: Also, I'd advise against ever using `!` in TypeScript (yes, I'm sure there are rare exceptions that someone could explicate). You should be able to prove that a variable is not null. If you can't, then there is likely a bug in your code (or your type definitions are too weak).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PassportJS does not declare any properties of the [`User` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a314c604f61aaf206104dfdf7256ea2224eefad0/types/passport/index.d.ts#L20). You can extend this definition by merging it with the following in your code:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      id: string
    }
  }
}
```

and your code should compile.

But where do you expect the `user.id` to be filled? Have you written your own code for that? Or does PassportJS fill this property although it does not declare it?

(I was able to "fool" the Typescript compiler by replacing `user!.id` with `user["id"]`, perhaps because I did not use the `--strict` option.)

Comment: I believe that `user.id` is filled when serializing or deserializing the user. It provides some info on the user. I haven't written anything for it, it's built into passport, in the same way that `req.logout()` is built right in.

Using `user["id"]` throws the same error.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, look again, please.

Comment: Nice answer, just a small nitpick: "overwrite" is the wrong term, this is [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error and I solved it as below:

I made IUser interface:

```
import type { Document } from "mongoose";

interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  hash: string;
  salt: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

export default IUser;
```

And I use it in user model:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import IUser from "../types/User";

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    hash: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

And, in the user controller, I used it like so:

```
import type { Request, Response } from "express";
import { genPassword } from "../utils/passwordUtils";
import User from "../models/userModel";
import IUser from "../types/User";

export const getUserProfile = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const currentUser = req.user as IUser;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(currentUser._id);

    if (user) {
      res.json({ success: true, user });
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }
};

export const updateUserProfile = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const currentUser = req.user as IUser;
  const user = await User.findById(currentUser._id);

  if (user) {
    user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
    if (req.body.password) {
      const saltHash = genPassword(req.body.password);
      const salt = saltHash.salt;
      const hash = saltHash.hash;
      user.hash = hash;
      user.salt = salt;
    }
    const updatedUser = await user.save();
    res.json({ success: true, user: updatedUser });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }
};
```