# How to access property of req.user in express, passport, typescript

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am a beginner in express and am working on creating an authentication feature using email and password.

I have completed the authenticator but am looking to protect the api route with user roles.
After authentication, `console.log(req.user)` will give me the properties of the user as shown below.

```
{
  firstName: 'test',
  lastName: 'test',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password: 'password',
  role: 'user',
  createdAt: '2022-08-31T05:46:07.573Z',
  updatedAt: '2022-08-31T05:46:07.573Z'
}
```

So when I try to do conditional branching with `req.user.role`, I get an error saying undefined.

```
Property 'role' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
```

The result is the same when trying to access as "req.user.attributes.role", and the result will be ubdefined.

Also, if you try the following URL method, you will get an error in the "passport.deserializeUser" section.

[extend definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632958/property-id-does-not-exist-on-type-user-with-passport-and-typescript)

```
Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'false | User | null | undefined'.
  Type 'import("/Users/takeshi/FanFundBackEnd/db/entity/user").default' is not assignable to type 'Express.User'.
    Types of property 'role' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("/Users/takeshi/FanFundBackEnd/db/entity/user").UserRole | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

How to access property of req.user ?

---

isAdmin.ts=>if user type is 'user', return http status 401.

```
export const isAdmin = (req: Request, res: Response, next:NextFunction) => {
  if(req.user.role != 'user'){
//"req.user.role" has error.Property 'role' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
    console.log('Check User type is not user')
    next();
  }
  res.status(401).json({"message": "Unauthrized, Check Your User Type "});
};
```

---

passportjs

```
const local = new Strategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserController.getUser(email);
    if (!user) {
      console.log("unknown User")
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
    }
    const c = user.password!;
    if (await bcrypt.compare(password, c.toString())){
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      console.log("invalid password")
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error, null);
  }
});

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('serialize', user);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user: User, done) => {
  console.log('deserialize');
  if (user) {
    done(null, user);
  } else {
    throw new Error('User does not exist');
  }
  
});

passport.use(local);
```

---

Comment: Does optional chaining works for the first part.? For example: `req.user?.role`

Comment: @sh2a
"req.user?.role" has same error.Property 'role' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)

Comment: @toyotaSupra
I have edited my question. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Express types object

[Great article from logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/)

in your case, you can extend the Express.User

```
import usertypes from './usertypes'
export {};
declare global {
 namespace Express {
  export interface User {
   data?: usertypes;
  }
 }
}
```

now you can access it via `user.data?.role`