# Error creating verifyTokenAdmin middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to create two middlewares, an authentication middleware and a middleware that checks if the user in question has "isAdmin" true inside its database.
The authentication middleware works perfectly, but to make the admin middleware work, I tried to put `req.users = data;` inside, but it returns me the error:

```
Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)
```

auth middleware:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

interface TokenPayload {
  id: string;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
}

export default async function authMiddleware(
  req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction
  ) {
    const { authorization }  = req.headers;

    if (!authorization) {
      return res.status(401).json('Invalid Authorization');
    };

    const token = authorization.replace('Bearer', ' ').trim();

    try {
      const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET as string;
      const data = jwt.verify(token, secret);

      req.users = data;

      const { id } = data as TokenPayload;

      req.userId = id;

      return next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).json(err);
    }
}
```

In auth middleware admin, in users it returns the same error

```
Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)
```

auth middleware admin

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import authMiddleware from './AuthMiddlewares';

  
export default async function authAdminMiddleware(
    req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction,
) {
    authMiddleware(req, res, () => {
        if (req.users.isAdmin) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.status(403).json("You are not alowed to do that!");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to declare the additional property `users` in your `req` object:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      users: any
    }
  }
}
```

(See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633329/16462950).)

Comment: I did that and it fixed the error but now I always fall into error 403 (catch from middleware auth admin)

Comment: res.status(403).json("You are not alowed to do that!");

Comment: Does the JWT contain an `isAdmin` claim? That what you seem to assume when you effectively let `req.users = jwt.verify(token, secret);`.

Comment: ```             const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, secret, {
                expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRES_LOGIN,
            })
```

Comment: When I create the token in the controller I do it like this

Comment: How can I make it contain isAdmin? Could you show me the code?

Comment: Can you put in a `console.log(req.users)` and post here what it logs?

Comment: {
  id: '36503532-dd23-4d21-9cae-507d515625a8',
  isAdmin: false,
  iat: 1671549303,
  exp: 1671808503
}
{
  id: '36503532-dd23-4d21-9cae-507d515625a8',
  isAdmin: false,
  iat: 1671549303,
  exp: 1671808503
}

Comment: isAdmin is true in the database, but it is returning like this in console.log

Comment: There you have it: `isAdmin: false`.

Comment: I checked once more and this is true in the database

Comment: That's a new problem, and it requires you to post the code how to sign the JWT. Best as a new question.

Comment: I had a token from when this user was still "isAdmin" false, I launched a new authentication and that was resolved. Thank you for your help